# Способ сгенерировать SOAP server из готового WSDL

Tags: java, soap, wsdl

Добрый день. Есть WSDL файл полученный с рабочего SOAP сервера, есть некое оборудование которое посылает SOAP запросы и хочет получить ответ от моего SOAP сервера. Есть ли способы сгенерировать из WSDL SOAP сервер?

Comment: Посмотрите утилитку wsdl2java от Apache

Comment: wsdl - это описание веб-сервиса. Это стандартизированная документация по веб-сервисам.
Многие системы не могут вызывать веб-сервис, не обратившись к wsdl. 
У различных систем своеобразные требования к веб-сервисам. Именно поэтому предоставляется wsdl, а специалисты могут подогнать эти wsdl под себя. По этому, вноси настройки серверу аналогично данному WSDL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего, это поможет:

- непосредственно Axis 2 от Apache: https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/index.html
- старый добрый SoapUI: https://www.soapui.org/soap-and-wsdl/soap-code-generation.html
- или же IntelliJ IDEA: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/generate-java-code-from-wsdl-or-wadl-dialog.html